# Brocade FCX terminal length

Tags: console, brocade

I have a Brocade FCX-4XG and I'm connected to the serial console.  I would like to change the terminal length of this console to facilitate scripting, but unlike a cisco or juniper, it's not terribly obvious how to do this...

```
FCX648 Switch#term 
  monitor   
FCX648 Switch#
FCX648 Switch(config)#term 
Unrecognized command
FCX648 Switch(config)#
FCX648 Switch(config)#console 
  timeout   Idle timeout
FCX648 Switch(config)#
```

Any ideas how to do this?  The manual doesn't seem to say either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a bit late but if you haven't found an answer yet, the command you are looking for is `skip-page-display` entered from an `enabled prompt`.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I am not in the lab so I can't check... I will let you know whether this worked tomorrow